# How do I change the Tab text and the URL of my landing page

Tags: mediawiki

I just installed MediaWiki on my laptop and got it running fine.

I'm stuck with how to change the Tab text of the tabs that appear at the top of the page, left of `Read | Edit | View History`.

Right now, the tabs read `Page | Discussion`, but I'd like to change it to `Bikes | Discussion`. How can I do that? I've gone mad trying to figure out how to do this. I've found all sorts of information on editing certain pages with `MediaWiki:****` to do this, but where are these pages located and how to I reach them?

Also, I've noticed that many Wiki sites have a URL like http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page -> Note the word wiki in the URL. Mine reads `http://localhost/bikes/index.php/Main_Page`. How can I change the word `bikes` to `wiki`. I've Installed MediaWiki into a folder called bikes.

I'm doing all this on a Laptop running Windows 7 64Bit and using Apache and PHP

Can you please help me?

Comment: In the future it might be easier to get help if you ask one question at a time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The name of the page view tab for the main namespace can be altered by changing the system message at `MediaWiki:Mainpage-nstab` (for your default language), and then `MediaWiki:Mainpage-nstab/ar` (Arabic), `MediaWiki:Mainpage-nstab/en` (English) etc for all other languages. (In older versions of MediaWiki this was called `MediaWiki:Nstab-main`.)

   To find out the name of a system message, you can append [`&uselang=qqx`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:System_message#Finding_messages_and_documentation) to the end of any url, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software?uselang=qqx
2. To change the url format, you have to do two things: Define `$wgScriptPath` and `$wgArticlePath` in LocalSettings.php, and create a rewriterule on the server. There are plenty of threads here on SO about that, and also a very good [tutorial for Apache at mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache).
   To get a Wikipedia like structure, try something like this in LocalSettings.php (from the above url):

   `$wgScriptPath = "/w";
   $wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";`
   And then on your server (e.g. in `.htaccess`, depending on your configuration)

   `RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]`

Comment: What does `MediWiki:Nstab-Main` mean? Is this a page? If yes, where do I find it or how do I access it? I've gone crazy trying to find these things beginning with MediaWiki like I mentioned in my question. Can you help me with this part?

Comment: Yes, it's the name of a page. In your case `http://localhost/bikes/index.php/MediaWiki:Nstab-main` It is a page just like anyone else on your wiki, in the MediaWiki namespace

Comment: Thanks. In the end,this media wiki is just too difficult to use. I wish it was more point n click and WYSIWYG rather than what it is. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Awesome answer. It seems for 1.27 it is called MediaWiki:Mainpage-nstab.

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect the (no longer so) new name.